# Kubernetes network policy prevents NFS PVC from mounting

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

I have Ganesha NFS server provisioner installed in my cluster as STS according to the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-ganesha-server-and-external-provisioner/blob/master/docs/deployment.md#in-kubernetes---deployment-of-1-replica). I run it with just a mounted block storage PVC.

I deploy a separate NFS server per namespace and I want to limit which pods in the namespace have access to the NFS server. I create the following network policy for ingress that allows access to the NFS server (labeled `name=nfs-server`) from pods in the same namespace with a label `app-name=my-app` (all ports):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  labels:
    name: allow-ingress-nfs
  name: allow-ingress-nfs
  namespace: "my-namespace"
spec:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app-name: my-app
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      name: nfs-server
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

This is the NFS server pod (from STS):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    name: nfs-server
  name: nfs-server-0
  namespace: "my-namespace"
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - -provisioner=my-namespace-nfs
    env:
    - name: POD_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: status.podIP
    - name: SERVICE_NAME
      value: nfs-server
    - name: POD_NAMESPACE
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
    image: registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/nfs-provisioner:v4.0.8
    name: nfs-server
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /export
      name: export
  volumes:
  - name: export
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: nfs-export
```

I try to mount a PVC of this NFS server from the following pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app-name: my-app
    name: nginx
  name: nginx-74c5d976b7-g782p
  namespace: "my-namespace"
spec:
  containers:
    image: my/image
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /mnt/files
      name: files
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: files
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: files
```

This is the PVC:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  name: files
  namespace: "my-namespace"
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
  storageClassName: my-namespace-nfs
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: pvc-uuid
```

This is the NFS storage class:

```yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: my-namespace-nfs
mountOptions:
- vers=4.1
provisioner: my-namespace-nfs
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

However, pods get stuck in `CreatingContainer` with the following error:

```
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t nfs -o vers=4.1 10.245.245.191:/export/pvc-name /var/lib/kubelet/pods/id/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/pvc-name
Output: mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

I've observed the same behavior in DigitalOcean Kubernetes 1.27 (they use Cilium) with non-shared CPU nodes and GKE 1.26

If I delete all network policies the issue disappears completely.

Not sure if this affects anything but I do not run Ganesha in privileged mode and I limit it by mem/CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it didn't work and behaved "randomly" is because ingress network policy allows connections to the pod only from the same node.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

> When a pod is isolated for ingress, the only allowed connections into the pod are those **from the pod's node** and those allowed by the ingress list of some NetworkPolicy that applies to the pod for ingress.

Answer (score 1):

There's no provision for the server (`NFS` pod) to send back the necessary information, thats why you have a connection timeout when trying to mount the `NFS` volume.

lets create a egress network policy for the NFS server to allow it to communicate back to the client pods, something like the example below, if that still dont work that might be a firewall issue.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-egress-nfs
  namespace: "my-namespace"
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      name: nfs-server
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app-name: my-app
```

Comment: I do not filter egress at all so instead I just added ingress rule allowing NFS server pod to contact clients (I completely missed that the server contacts the clients via ephemeral callback port) and it resolved my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I think I hurried up. The issue still persist, it's just it's completely random, sometime it works, sometimes it doesn't